# sysprocess in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Some naive questions the numbers in sysprocesses.
What I conclude by looking at the numbers cpu, physical_io, memusage

Do any of these numbers sum to a finite amount?
Also, I notice that when I run a query, that the status beomes 'runnable'.
When the query stops it becomes 'sleeping'.
However the resources-used figures are still up
Am I still consuming these resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260456(SQL.80).aspx):

> cpu: Cumulative CPU time for the process.
>
> physical_io: Cumulative disk reads and writes for the process.

Since they are cumulative,they won't sum to anything.  I'm fairly certain things haven't changed (much) since [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170360) article where they define cpu as milliseconds of user-mode time consumed by the process and physical_io as synchronous reads and writes.

> memusage: Number of pages in the procedure cache that are currently allocated to this process. A negative number indicates that the process is freeing memory allocated by another process.

This is a currently allocated number, so this is indeed the actual number of pages allocated to that process.

It's tough to draw a conclusion alone from cpu and physical_io as the numbers are cumulative.  Though often inconclusive, I personally just use the columns to find outliers when diagnosing an issue.